# Decomposition of $\mu^{free}$ for the Ising-Dyson Model

Tags: ising-model

For the nearest neighbours Ising-Model in any dimension, it is known that 
$$
   \mu^{free}_\beta= \frac{1}{2} \mu^{+}_\beta+\frac{1}{2} \mu^{-}_\beta
$$
for any inverse of temperature $\beta>0$.

Is the same valid for dimension $d=1$, with a long-range interaction $J(i,j)=\frac{1}{|i-j|^\alpha}1_{i\neq j} $ for $\alpha \in (1,2]$? I remember a professor once told me the Ising Model with long-range interaction in dimension $d$ roughly behaves like the nearest neighbours Ising Model in dimension $d+1$. So I supposed we would expect such phenomena but are there strong reasons to believe so? Is it proved? At least maybe for a range of temperatures? I appreciate any references.

Comment: What exactly is $\mu_\beta$ here?

Comment: By $\mu^\#_\beta$ I am denoting the weak limit of the measures $\mu^\#_{\Lambda_n,\beta}$ for some $\Lambda_n \uparrow \mathbb{Z}$. Where $\#$ is the boundary condition. $\# = +,-$ means setting all the spins out of $\Lambda_n$ as $+1$ or $-1$. And for $\#=free$ I mean to disregard the interactions between the pairs of spins with one side inside and another outside $\Lambda_n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this follows from a [recent result by Aran Raoufi](https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.07608). His result is much more general and applies to an extremely large class of graphs.